# Xpath: Select node but not specific child elements

Tags: xpath

I have a structure similar to the following:

```
<page id='1'>
  <title>Page 1</title>    
  <page id='2'>
    <title>Sub Page 1</title>
  </page>
  <page id='3'>
    <title>Sub Page 2</title>
  </page>    
</page>
<page id='4'>
  <title>Page 2</title>
</page>
```

I need to select a page by Id but if that page has descendant pages I don't want to return those elements, but I do want the other elements of that page. If I select Page 1 I want to return title but not the child pages...

```
//page[@id=1]
```

The above gets me page 1, but how do I exclude the sub pages? Also, There could be any arbitrary number of elements in a page.

```
//page[@id=1]/*[not(self::page)]
```

I have found that this gets me the data I want. However, that data comes back as an array of objects with one object per element and apparently excludes the element names???. I am using PHP SimpleXML for what it is worth.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a short and simple solution. :)

Comment: "However, that data comes back as an array of objects with one object per element." How is that different from what you want/need?

Comment: The data comes back in a different format depending on the xpath query, I get an array of SimpleXMLElement with a single string in each and is missing the the element names. The first case returns a single SimpleXMLElement object with all the expected key value pairs. I don't understand why, perhaps I will open another question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Use**:

```
//page[@id=$yourId]/node()[not(self::page)]
```

This selects all nodes that are not `page` and that are children of any `page` in the document, the string value of whose `id` attribute is equal to the string contained in `$yourId` (most probably you would substitute `$yourId` above with a specific, desired string, such as `'1'`).

**Here is a simple XSLT-based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pId" select="3"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select="//page[@id=$pId]/node()[not(self::page)]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (wrapped in a single top node to make it well-formed):

```
<pages>
    <page id='1'>
        <title>Page 1</title>
        <page id='2'>
            <title>Sub Page 1</title>
        </page>
        <page id='3'>
            <title>Sub Page 2</title>
        </page>
    </page>
    <page id='4'>
        <title>Page 2</title>
    </page>
</pages>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<title>Sub Page 2</title>
```

**Do note**: One assumption made is that an `id` value uniquely identifies a `page`. If this is not so, the proposed XPath expression will select *all* `page` elements whose `id` attribute has a string valu of `$yourId`.

If this is the case and only one `page` element must be selected, the OP must specify which one of the many `page` elements with this `id` should be selected.

**For example, it may be the first**:

```
(//page[@id=$yourId]/node()[not(self::page)])[1]
```

**or the last**:

```
(//page[@id=$yourId]/node()[not(self::page)])[last()]
```

**or ...**

Comment: While this looks exactly right, it doesn't actually work.. I am not sure if there is something wrong with xpath in PHP's simple xml, but this returns multiple copies of the requested page???

Comment: @Ben: This may happen only if more than one `page` can have the same value of its `id` attribute. I have updated my answer to cover this case. I also provide a simple verification showing that the initial XPath expression selects exactly one `page` element if an `id` value uniquely identifies a `page`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only interested in the title element, this would work:

```
//page[@id=1]/title
```

If however you need other sub elements of page, I'm not sure XPath is the right tool for you.
Sounds more like something that an XSLT would be suited for, since what you are really doing is transforming your data.

Comment: Updated answer with further information. Feel free to upvote if it's helpful in anyway. :)

Comment: Thanks, I am starting to think Xpath maybe cannot do this. I can always write something to process out the data I want but was hoping to do it at the data level.

Answer (score 1):

If the page always has a title:

```
//page[@id='1']/*[not(boolean(./title))]
```