# Selenium webdriver : exclude child node

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Here is the sample HTML Code :

```
  <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
   <tbody>
     <tr>
     <tr class="tinyfont">
     <tr height="2px">
     <tr height="1px">
     <tr height="1px">
     <tr>
     <tr height="2px">
     <tr height="1px">
     <tr height="1px">
     <tr height="2px">
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

I am using selenium webdriver.
I have received the all the child elements from this code but now I want to exclude one particular child element in logic, how I can exclude one of the child element from my array.
I want to exclude tr[6] child element..

```
   List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody  //*"));        

 ArrayList<String> al1 = new ArrayList<String>();

for(WebElement ele:list){
 String className = ele.getAttribute("class");
 System.out.println("Class name = "+className);
    al1.add(className);
 }
```

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: I think this might be what you are looking for?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115917/xpath-select-node-but-not-specific-child-elements

Comment: didnt work with Selenium webdriver..

Comment: Which element do you want to exclude? A sample of the html you are working with would help.

Comment: Are you sure? there is no `td` ?

Answer (score 1):

Either omit the 6th table row, then select all descendants:

```
/html/body/table/tbody/tr[position() != 6]//*
```

or only select all table rows that are not at position 1 and have an attribute (and then select their descendants):

```
/html/body/table/tbody/tr[position() = 1 or @*]//*
```

or to be more specific, also check the attribute name:

```
/html/body/table/tbody/tr[position() = 1 or @height or @class]//*
```

Comment: If it solved your problem, you might consider accepting the answer, have a look at the [FAQ].

Answer (score 0):

Is it always element 6 that you want to avoid? If it is, use a for look with an increment and just avoid element 6 with an if statement.

```
int numOfElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody  //*")).count();

ArrayList<String> al1 = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 1; i<= numOfElements; i++) 
{
   if(i!=6)
   {
       String className = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr["+i+"]")).getAttribute("class");
       System.out.println("Class name = "+className);
       al1.add(className);
   }
}
```

This wont sound like a solution that you are looking for, but it still is a round about way to achieve what you want. Off the top of my head, I cant think of another way unless you have a attribute that contains something to compare off of or to exclude

Comment: Thanks..can use some part of the solution..     /html/body/table/tbody/tr[position() != 6]//* did the trick for me..