# XPath can't get whole tree for matching child

Tags: xml, xpath

Given this XML:

```
<Orders>
    <Order>
        <Item name="xyz"/>
    </Order>
    <Order>
        <Item name="123"/>
    </Order>
</Orders>
```

Why does /Orders/Order[Item[@name='123']] return:

```
<Order>
    <Item name="123" />
</Order>
```

But /Orders[Order[Item[@name='123']]] returns:

```
<Orders>
    <Order>
        <Item name="xyz" />
    </Order>
    <Order>
        <Item name="123" />
    </Order>
</Orders>
```

In this second scenario the matching on name is ignored.

What XPath do I need to get back:

```
<Orders>
    <Order>
        <Item name="123" />
    </Order>
</Orders>
```

Comment: Jim Garrison already gave you a nice explanation about it, if you want to limit child nodes from showing up, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115917/xpath-select-node-but-not-specific-child-elements)

Answer (score 2):

The reason the second example returns what it does is because your expression

```
/Orders[Order[Item[@name='123']]]
```

says:

1. Locate an `Orders` node
2. That contains an `Order` nmde
3. That contains an `Item` node
4. Where that `Item` node has an attribute `name` with value `123`

Notice that you focus on the `Orders` node, so that is what is returned, i.e. the *entire* `Orders` node.

What you want does not exist in the source document, so you are asking for a *transformation* to occur.  My XPath is somewhat rusty but I don't believe XPath by itself is capable of doing this.  You will probably need to use XSLT to transform the XML to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is, given the XML posted, you can't get that output using XPath.

XPath is meant for locating part of an XML (XPath 1.0 especially). Notice that opening-tag, content, and corresponding closing-tag is considered one unit, an element node. So, such `<Orders>` element which contains only one `<Order>` child element that you expect to return is not part of the original XML, hence can't be returned using XPath.

> *XPath is a language for addressing parts of an XML document, designed to be used by both XSLT and XPointer.* [Reference: [XPath 1.0 Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)]