# How to exclude a node using xml2

Tags: r, xml, xpath, xml2

I have searched around for the past few days and I see in XPath v2 you can use the 'except' operator, but haven't been able to figure out how xml2 can handle this.

This link is sort of what I want to do, but this is specific to XPath, and I'm trying to do a blanket exclusion of a node [like in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115917/xpath-select-node-but-not-specific-child-elements).

For example, my test document is a `.docx` which I unzip and read. It has body text and a table. I want to read all the body text, except anything in a table. I can read both, but I can't figure out how to exclude all the `w:tbl`. Any `not` or `except` operators don't seem to work.

With `xml_find_all` it scrapes anything within those nodes, without exception.

```
bodytext <- xml2::xml_find_all(doc, "//w:p")
tabletext <- xml2::xml_find_all(doc, "//w:tbl")
```

Comment: Although thre is a "2" in the name, libxml2 does NOT implement the XPath 2.0 standard. It implements only XPath 1.0 , see http://xmlsoft.org/ . If you want XPath 2.0:  See  this answer from 2013: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16659329/202553

Comment: Please post a relevant sample of docx xml for us to help. You can use the xpath's brackets `[...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are querying all existing `w:p` but `w:tbl` is containing instances of `w:p` - the following only select paragraph located in body:

```
xml2::xml_find_all(doc, "//w:body/w:p")
```

Note that to explore content of a docx, you can use `officer::docx_summary(officer::read_docx('/path/to/document.docx'))` that will return a data.frame with content, index, etc. as illustrated below.

```
  doc_index content_type style_name             text level num_id
1         1    paragraph       <NA>                     NA     NA
2         2    paragraph  heading 1 Table of content    NA     NA
3         3    paragraph       <NA>                     NA     NA
4         4    paragraph  heading 2     dataset iris    NA     NA
```

Comment: I was getting an error with that: "attempt to apply non-function." However, I removed "doc$doc_obj$get()" and it works. Thank you so much, now see how the node substructure can work. Also that officer::docx_summary is amazing. That might work even better. Thanks!